# Object passed to the method in java

Tags: java, object

I'm try to simulate a mobile phone. I've created the following methods:

1. load
2. call
3. sendTextMessage
4. getLoad
5. getTotalMinutesCalled
6. changeRate
7. printSummary
8. passLoadTo

My problem is that when I pass an object to the `passLoadTo()` method, and then print the summary of that object, it doesn't change the state of that object.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MobilePhone {

    private double credit;
    private int totalMinutes;
    private double ratePerCall;
    private int numOfText;

    MobilePhone()
    {
        credit = 0;
        totalMinutes = 0;
        ratePerCall = 6.50;
        numOfText = 0;
    }

    public void load(double pesos) {
        if(pesos > 25) {
            credit = credit + pesos;
        } else {
            //System.out.println("The attempting to use this service is forbidden.");
            //System.out.println();
        }
    }

    //other code

    public void printSummary() {
        System.out.printf("Credit left: P%.2f" ,getLoadLeft());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total call duration "+getTotalMinutesCalled()+" mins");
        System.out.printf("Rate per call: P%.2f" ,ratePerCall);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Number of text message send: " +getNumTextMessage());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void passLoadTo(MobilePhone dest, double amount) {
        if(credit > amount) {
            credit = credit - amount;
            dest.load(amount);  
        }  else {
            System.out.println("fail");
            System.out.println("The attempting to use this service is forbidden.");
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

this code is for testing purposes:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MobilePhone mp = new MobilePhone();
        MobilePhone mp1 = new MobilePhone();

        mp.load(30);
        mp.printSummary();
        mp.changeRate(1);
        mp.printSummary();


        mp.call(1);
        mp.printSummary();

        System.out.println(mp.getTotalMinutesCalled());

        mp.passLoadTo(mp1, 30);
        mp.printSummary();

        mp1.printSummary();
    }
}
```

What i want is whenever i created a 2 mobile object(mp and mp1) and call mp.passLoadTo(mp1,1) method, the summary of the mp1 summary prints the load i added from mp to mp1

Comment: What is the output you get and what is the output you expect?

Comment: Also, in `call` I expect `totalMinutes = minutes;` should be `totalMinutes += minutes;`

Comment: @JesseJ passLoadTo, it's before the code blocks

Comment: @JesseJ I stated it above the method `passLoadTo`

Comment: @selig what i want is whenever i created a 2 mobile object(mp and mp1) and call `mp.passLoadTo(mp1,1)` method, the summary of the mp1 summary prints the load i added from mp to mp1

Comment: Also, edit your question to add what @selig asked, it will improve your question.

Comment: Everything is fine except that `mp1` can't be loaded for amount less than 25 (as stated in your `if` check of `load()` method)

Comment: Selig's suggestion was perhaps more literal than you're interpreting it: literally, what is the output of your program as you're seeing it? And in your ideal world, what would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary problem is this:

```
 if(credit > amount) {
```

You are checking if credit is greater than amount, but you're only loading 30 and spending 30, which will fail `(30 > 30)`.

Comment: The first part of your answer is wrong, the second part is the correct answer. ( I upvoted btw)

Comment: I revised the question to clarify what I meant by the first part (now the second part). I got hung up on 'simulating a cell phone'. Sending money to another cell is a strange concept to me. (And I deleted the other part, because I suppose it makes sense if you can do that.)

Comment: Yes, I see what you're saying now.  Also the logic he wrote makes no sense.  If mp1 has 20, and you call mp1.load(mp2,5), the code will debit 5 from mp1.  It will then try to load 5 to mp2, but will fail, since there is a 25 credit minimum for the load.  Money leak, that is even worse than a memory leak! (at least for your wallet).